# psutil get_threads() returns an empty list

Tags: python, psutil

I'm trying to return all threads from a pid but get an empty list (`[]`). This is the code:

```
import psutil        
p = psutil.Process(3133)        
p.get_threads()
```

Note: pid 3133 exists and I'm using Python 3.3.5 and psutil 2.1.1 (32 bit).

Comment: Is the process in question running as your username, or something else (system, another user, etc)?

Comment: I think it might work if we run it with elevated permissions; which OS do you use, Linux or Windows?

Comment: Windows 2008...however, that will require 'tweaking' before executing and in some cases, sadly thats not possible.

Comment: I see what you mean, but without the elevated permissions I don't see how you can get information about system processes' threads.  Maybe you could test if the process user is equal to current user, and if not, launch a utility script as a new process with elevated permissions.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can only retrieve thread information from processes running as yourself.